# Form Structure ruined on different PC. Datagridview display error

Tags: c#, datagridview

Vague Title.. but I don't know the correct terminology for this issue.

I have a Dialog Form that pops up on my main form button press.
On my design PC it works great.. no issues.

[image]
On a trial Laptop it comes up completely distorted in the datagridview
[image]

(the green lines are supposed to be there) - I just did the screen shot after "selecting" some rows.

I have autoscale = DPI on it.

This computer had severe issues with display on all forms until i did autoscale DPI not FONT, however for this one it has fixed the form and font, but the datagrid view is totally messed up.

Any ideas what i can check??

Comment: Is that the desktop shining through??

Comment: @TaW Yep it is.  I literally have no idea why this is happening.  "Comment" column is set to FILL

Comment: It looks like the original PC is remembering last settings.  So manual changes you made are not in the code.  The lap top is missing the manual settings.